# Create APFS/HFS+ partition on Linux and share it via network

Tags: linux, networking, macos, hfs+, apfs

I want to store all my files and documents on a local server at my home instead locally on a single PC.

Now I'm wondering if it's possible to create a APFS or HFS+ partition on a Linux system (like Debian) and then share it via network, so I can access it from multiple macOS and Windows systems.

Alternativelly I also thought about sharing a ext4 partition via Samba but then I will get this annoying Apple Double Files. I know that there are tools to get rid of these files, but I thought maybe I can directly share a APFS or HFS+ partition.

Comment: Which part of this are you stuck on? Creating the drive, sharing the drive, reading it over SMB?

Comment: @Tetsujin I'm wondering if it's even possible to create a APFS or HFS+ partition on Linux and share it (maybe via SMB or some other protocols).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Linux does not have a complete APFS filesystem driver – AFAIK there's only a read-only one, and its development seems to have stalled as well.

But the problem isn't just the filesystem, it's also that Linux doesn't offer a programming interface to store "resource forks" the way macOS (or Windows) does. The closest equivalent would be extended attributes (xattrs), which *are* already available on ext4, but they have a relatively small size limit (whereas HFS resource forks or NTFS alternate streams can grow as large as any file).

Still, you can tell Samba to store resource forks as xattrs using the vfs_fruit module:

```
vfs objects = fruit
fruit:resource = xattr
```

Comment: +1 I'd definitely stick with HFS+ rather than APFS for now on any 'foreign' OS, as it's better-documented & therefore easier to implement & maintain.

Comment: I don't really see the point of using HFS+ here though – it doesn't help Samba with anything in particular; even though it's capable of storing resource forks, Linux and Samba still have no better way of _managing_ them than through the same xattr API.

Comment: It's just the intractability of APFS, really. You can't even fix them properly on a Mac if they start to play up at all. tbh, I've never had need to share to Mac from anything else, so I've never had to fight with any of this. I've always shared from Mac, though these days I've got rid of the last of the Win machines & my only nix is really little more than an appliance, so problems gone.

Comment: Sounds a lot like Btrfs – great in concept but still lacking in repairability after many years.

Comment: @user1686 That seems to be very interessting. So if I would use a ext4 partition and the vfs_fruit module I can get rid of the Apple Double files because they are directly stored as extended attributes, right? You said something about the "relatively small size limit" of the attributes. What would happen if this limit is reached? Or is this just a theoretical problem?